# What is the meaning of the letters in CCISS?

Tags: linux, raid, device

I know that CCISS is the name give to a RAID device that comes from COMPAQ/HP, but why this name? Does it have any meaning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

my guess:

Compaq Command Interface for SCSI-3 Support

see CCISS Interface Specification
http://sourceforge.net/projects/cciss/files/CCISS%20Interface%20Specification/CISS%20Interface%20Specification%20May%202008/OpenCISS_Specification.pdf/download

Comment: There it is! A mystery is solved.

Answer (score 1):

It probably had a meaning inside of HP/Compaq years ago (I imagine deep within the Storage Systems Engineering group), but as far as I can tell, it's never been published.

I've wondered that myself.

"Card-Controlled Integrated System Storage"?

Answer (score 1):

Command and control interface subsystem?

Answer (score 1):

Command and Control Interface SubSystem